# drive api set appProperties

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

how to set appProperties in google Drive api in php?

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName($f->getFilename());
$file->setMimeType(mime_content_type($f->getPathname()));
$file->setParents(array($dest));

$object = new stdClass();
$object->projecto = 'xpto';                
$file->setAppProperties($object);

$data = file_get_contents($f->getPathname());

$createdFile = $driveService->files->create($file, array(
     'uploadType' => 'multipart',
     'data' => $data
));
```

i try this:

```
$file->setAppProperties(array(array('projecto' => 'xpto')));
```

or this:

```
$file->setAppProperties(array('projecto' => 'xpto'));
```

create a file, but dont set properties..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that much familiar with PHP syntax, but make sure that the `setAppproperties` is a JSON object. It's indicated on [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/properties) that its a key-pair value that you can set on the application requesting it. It's even formatted as such in the API Explorer.

> You can use Drive API to add your own properties to a Drive file. These properties are stored as key/value pairs on the Drive file.

Do note that by default, the `appProperties` isn't part of the response object once `create` has been called. You'll have to specify it on the `fields` call for it to be part of the response.